# How to simulate android devices shake?

Tags: android

I have a challenge that I need shaking android device 100 times in 10s, is there something like API or sending fake accelerator data to get it?
In addition, I'm not sure if the application can recognize shaking at that high frequency.

Answer (score -1):

You can use adb command to simulate device shaking like this:

```
adb shell input keyevent 82
```

But I don't know what do you mean by api with this question?

Comment: keyevent 82 is KEYCODE_MENU, cannot simulate device shaking.